# From where can i get libmp3lame.so file?

Tags: android, linux

can anybody give me links to dowlnload libmp3lame.so file.I want to convert mp3 stream to pcm.
I want to do it using android ndk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following url

http://mandrivausers.org/index.php?/topic/25941-where-to-get-libmp3lameso-solved/

http://hany.sk/~hany/RPM/libmp3lame.so.0.html

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: there is whole sourcecode but i dont know how to build it.i m using windows7 and want to use the .so file with android ndk.

Answer (score 1):

Google tells me you can get it [here on their official site](http://lame.sourceforge.net/index.php), which was the first result for lame mp3.